# Query a datetime in SQL Server 2005 Express 

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2005-express

How to query the rows based on `DateTime` in SQL Server 2005 Express installed on windows server 2008 r2?

I have code that selects rows based on from and to date values. It's working in my Windows 7 system . But, It's not working on Windows Server 2008 R2 ... Any help

```
this.filterreportTableAdapter.FillBy(this.cRdataset.filterreport_datatable, fromdate, todate);
```

and my SQL query is

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
WHERE DATE BETWEEN @fromdate and @todate
```

Comment: What datatype is your `DATE` column? (that's a **really bad** column name, btw - since it's a data type in version 2008 and onwards). What **values** are you passing in for `@fromdate` and `@todate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like date/time values are being passed as strings. This is always a bad idea, and formatting issues abound. The best approach here is simply: use correctly-typed parameters. if both client and server know it is a DateTime, then it is passed as a primitive vaue, not a string - thus no formatting problems.

Make sure that `fromdate` and `todate` in the c# are `DateTime`, and that `@fromdate`, `@todate` and `tablename.DATE` in the TSQL are `datetime`.

Answer (score 0):

Please set the datetime format same as the one on your windows 7 e.g. :  dd/MM/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you have a date format mistake when passing date parameters.
there are two solutions:
first, you can try to use date format that works everywhere that is:
YYYYMMDD ex : 20120722.
another solution is to make a DateDiff in sql query
Best regard

Comment: Or an *actual* solution... Use typed parameters, which aren't affected by formatting issues.